# GPO cannot install software from DFS folder

Tags: dfs

I use GPO for install software from a file share. I want to change the file share to a DFS folder. I've made a DFS folder over this this share. I've changed the path in the GPO. When I restarted a PC I saw this message:

"Event Type: Error 
Event Source: Application Management

Description: 
The install of application "application" from policy testGPO failed. The 
error was : The installation source for this product is not available. 
Verify that the source exists and that you can access it."

The GPO install works from the file share!
Do you have any idea wy it does not work from the DFS?

The share permission: Authenticated User - Read

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Does the computer have access to the share? Sounds like a permissions issue. Are you auditing security events on the DFS computer; it might show the access-denied error.

Comment: I can't see any acces-denied error for this computer. The isntall works with file share but it does not work whit DFS.

Comment: So that's a "yes I am auditing security events, and there are no events in the security log"?

Comment: Yes, I am auditing security events, and there are logon - logoff events only and there is not access denied event in the security log.